# Why isn't this SVG Animation being applied like it should?

Tags: css, svg, css-animations

I've used this css to animate another svg but it doesn't work here...not sure why. Can someone help?!

I just want this arrow to "draw" from left to right.

Here's the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 26.0.1, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 536 51" style="enable-background:new 0 0 536 51;" xml:space="preserve">
<style type="text/css">
    .st0{fill:#180640;}
</style>
<path class="st0" d="M535.3,0.9l-5.7-0.8l2.2,5.4L535.3,0.9z M181.3,6.5l0,0.5L181.3,6.5z M361.1,44.9l0-0.5L361.1,44.9z M1,50.2
    c0.2,0.5,0.2,0.5,0.2,0.5c0,0,0,0,0,0c0,0,0,0,0,0c0,0,0,0,0,0c0,0,0,0,0,0c0,0,0,0,0,0c0,0,0,0,0,0c0,0,0,0,0.1,0
    c0.1,0,0.1-0.1,0.2-0.1c0.2-0.1,0.5-0.2,1-0.4l-0.4-0.9c-0.4,0.2-0.8,0.3-1,0.4c-0.1,0-0.2,0.1-0.3,0.1c0,0,0,0-0.1,0c0,0,0,0,0,0
    c0,0,0,0,0,0c0,0,0,0,0,0c0,0,0,0,0,0c0,0,0,0,0,0c0,0,0,0,0,0C0.8,49.7,0.8,49.7,1,50.2z M6.2,48.6c0.8-0.3,1.7-0.7,2.7-1.1
    l-0.4-0.9c-1,0.4-1.9,0.8-2.7,1.1L6.2,48.6z M12.6,46c0.9-0.3,1.8-0.7,2.8-1.1L15,44c-1,0.4-1.9,0.7-2.8,1.1L12.6,46z M19,43.5
    c0.9-0.3,1.8-0.7,2.8-1.1l-0.4-0.9c-1,0.4-1.9,0.7-2.8,1.1L19,43.5z M25.5,41.1c0.9-0.3,1.8-0.7,2.8-1l-0.3-0.9
    c-0.9,0.3-1.9,0.7-2.8,1L25.5,41.1z M32,38.8c0.9-0.3,1.8-0.7,2.8-1l-0.3-0.9c-0.9,0.3-1.9,0.7-2.8,1L32,38.8z M38.5,36.5
    c0.9-0.3,1.9-0.6,2.8-1L41,34.6c-1,0.3-1.9,0.7-2.8,1L38.5,36.5z M45,34.3c0.9-0.3,1.9-0.6,2.8-0.9l-0.3-0.9c-1,0.3-1.9,0.6-2.8,0.9
    L45,34.3z M51.6,32.1c0.9-0.3,1.9-0.6,2.8-0.9l-0.3-1c-1,0.3-1.9,0.6-2.8,0.9L51.6,32.1z M58.2,30c0.9-0.3,1.9-0.6,2.8-0.9l-0.3-1
    c-1,0.3-1.9,0.6-2.8,0.9L58.2,30z M64.8,28c0.9-0.3,1.9-0.6,2.8-0.8l-0.3-1c-1,0.3-1.9,0.6-2.8,0.8L64.8,28z M71.4,26
    c0.9-0.3,1.9-0.5,2.8-0.8l-0.3-1c-1,0.3-1.9,0.5-2.9,0.8L71.4,26z M78.1,24.1c0.9-0.3,1.9-0.5,2.9-0.8l-0.3-1
    c-1,0.3-1.9,0.5-2.9,0.8L78.1,24.1z M84.7,22.3c1-0.3,1.9-0.5,2.9-0.8l-0.3-1c-1,0.3-1.9,0.5-2.9,0.8L84.7,22.3z M91.4,20.6
    c1-0.2,1.9-0.5,2.9-0.7l-0.2-1c-1,0.2-1.9,0.5-2.9,0.7L91.4,20.6z M98.1,18.9c1-0.2,1.9-0.5,2.9-0.7l-0.2-1c-1,0.2-1.9,0.5-2.9,0.7
    L98.1,18.9z M104.8,17.4c1-0.2,1.9-0.4,2.9-0.6l-0.2-1c-1,0.2-1.9,0.4-2.9,0.6L104.8,17.4z M111.6,15.9c1-0.2,1.9-0.4,2.9-0.6
    l-0.2-1c-1,0.2-1.9,0.4-2.9,0.6L111.6,15.9z M118.3,14.5c1-0.2,1.9-0.4,2.9-0.6l-0.2-1c-1,0.2-1.9,0.4-2.9,0.6L118.3,14.5z
     M125.1,13.2c1-0.2,1.9-0.4,2.9-0.5l-0.2-1c-1,0.2-1.9,0.3-2.9,0.5L125.1,13.2z M131.9,12c1-0.2,1.9-0.3,2.9-0.5l-0.2-1
    c-1,0.2-2,0.3-2.9,0.5L131.9,12z M138.7,10.9c1-0.1,1.9-0.3,2.9-0.4l-0.1-1c-1,0.1-2,0.3-2.9,0.4L138.7,10.9z M145.5,9.9
    c1-0.1,2-0.3,2.9-0.4l-0.1-1c-1,0.1-2,0.3-2.9,0.4L145.5,9.9z M152.4,9.1c1-0.1,2-0.2,2.9-0.3l-0.1-1c-1,0.1-2,0.2-2.9,0.3
    L152.4,9.1z M159.2,8.3c1-0.1,2-0.2,2.9-0.3l-0.1-1c-1,0.1-2,0.2-3,0.3L159.2,8.3z M166.1,7.7c1-0.1,2-0.1,3-0.2l-0.1-1
    c-1,0.1-2,0.1-3,0.2L166.1,7.7z M173,7.3c1-0.1,2-0.1,3-0.1l0-1c-1,0-2,0.1-3,0.1L173,7.3z M179.9,7c0.5,0,1,0,1.5,0l0-1
    c-0.5,0-1,0-1.5,0L179.9,7z M181.3,7c0.5,0,1,0,1.5,0l0-1c-0.5,0-1,0-1.5,0L181.3,7z M186.9,7c1,0,2,0.1,3,0.1l0-1c-1,0-2-0.1-3-0.1
    L186.9,7z M193.9,7.3c1,0.1,2,0.2,3,0.3l0.1-1c-1-0.1-2-0.2-3-0.3L193.9,7.3z M201,8c1,0.1,2,0.3,3,0.4l0.1-1c-1-0.1-2-0.3-3-0.4
    L201,8z M208,9.1c1,0.2,2,0.3,3,0.5l0.2-1c-1-0.2-2-0.4-3-0.5L208,9.1z M215,10.3c1,0.2,2,0.4,3,0.6l0.2-1c-1-0.2-2-0.4-3-0.6
    L215,10.3z M221.9,11.8c1,0.2,2,0.5,3,0.7l0.2-1c-1-0.2-2-0.5-3-0.7L221.9,11.8z M228.8,13.5c1,0.2,2,0.5,2.9,0.8l0.3-1
    c-1-0.3-2-0.5-3-0.8L228.8,13.5z M235.7,15.3c1,0.3,1.9,0.5,2.9,0.8l0.3-1c-1-0.3-2-0.5-2.9-0.8L235.7,15.3z M242.5,17.2
    c1,0.3,1.9,0.6,2.9,0.9l0.3-1c-1-0.3-1.9-0.6-2.9-0.9L242.5,17.2z M249.3,19.2c1,0.3,1.9,0.6,2.9,0.9l0.3-1c-1-0.3-1.9-0.6-2.9-0.9
    L249.3,19.2z M256.1,21.3c1,0.3,1.9,0.6,2.9,0.9l0.3-1c-1-0.3-1.9-0.6-2.9-0.9L256.1,21.3z M262.8,23.5c1,0.3,1.9,0.6,2.9,0.9l0.3-1
    c-1-0.3-1.9-0.6-2.9-0.9L262.8,23.5z M269.6,25.6c1,0.3,1.9,0.6,2.9,0.9l0.3-1c-1-0.3-1.9-0.6-2.9-0.9L269.6,25.6z M276.4,27.8
    c1,0.3,1.9,0.6,2.9,0.9l0.3-1c-1-0.3-1.9-0.6-2.9-0.9L276.4,27.8z M283.1,29.9c1,0.3,1.9,0.6,2.9,0.9l0.3-1c-1-0.3-1.9-0.6-2.9-0.9
    L283.1,29.9z M289.9,32c1,0.3,1.9,0.6,2.9,0.9l0.3-1c-1-0.3-1.9-0.6-2.9-0.9L289.9,32z M296.7,34.1c1,0.3,1.9,0.6,2.9,0.9l0.3-1
    c-1-0.3-1.9-0.6-2.9-0.9L296.7,34.1z M303.5,36.1c1,0.3,2,0.5,2.9,0.8l0.3-1c-1-0.3-1.9-0.5-2.9-0.8L303.5,36.1z M310.4,38
    c1,0.3,2,0.5,3,0.8l0.2-1c-1-0.2-2-0.5-2.9-0.8L310.4,38z M317.3,39.7c1,0.2,2,0.5,3,0.7l0.2-1c-1-0.2-2-0.5-3-0.7L317.3,39.7z
     M324.2,41.3c1,0.2,2,0.4,3,0.6l0.2-1c-1-0.2-2-0.4-3-0.6L324.2,41.3z M331.2,42.7c1,0.2,2,0.4,3,0.5l0.2-1c-1-0.2-2-0.3-3-0.5
    L331.2,42.7z M338.2,43.8c1,0.1,2,0.3,3,0.4l0.1-1c-1-0.1-2-0.3-3-0.4L338.2,43.8z M345.3,44.7c1,0.1,2,0.2,3,0.3l0.1-1
    c-1-0.1-2-0.2-3-0.3L345.3,44.7z M352.4,45.3c1,0.1,2,0.1,3,0.1l0-1c-1,0-2-0.1-3-0.1L352.4,45.3z M359.5,45.4c0.5,0,1,0,1.5,0l0-1
    c-0.5,0-1,0-1.5,0L359.5,45.4z M361.1,45.4c0.5,0,1,0,1.5,0l0-1c-0.5,0-1,0-1.5,0L361.1,45.4z M366.5,45.2c1,0,2-0.1,3-0.2l-0.1-1
    c-1,0.1-2,0.1-3,0.2L366.5,45.2z M373.5,44.8c1-0.1,2-0.2,3-0.3l-0.1-1c-1,0.1-2,0.2-3,0.3L373.5,44.8z M380.4,44.1
    c1-0.1,2-0.2,3-0.3l-0.1-1c-1,0.1-2,0.2-3,0.3L380.4,44.1z M387.3,43.3c1-0.1,2-0.3,3-0.4l-0.1-1c-1,0.1-2,0.3-2.9,0.4L387.3,43.3z
     M394.2,42.3c1-0.1,2-0.3,2.9-0.5l-0.2-1c-1,0.2-2,0.3-2.9,0.5L394.2,42.3z M401,41.2c1-0.2,2-0.3,2.9-0.5l-0.2-1
    c-1,0.2-2,0.3-2.9,0.5L401,41.2z M407.9,39.9c1-0.2,2-0.4,2.9-0.6l-0.2-1c-1,0.2-2,0.4-2.9,0.6L407.9,39.9z M414.7,38.6
    c1-0.2,1.9-0.4,2.9-0.6l-0.2-1c-1,0.2-1.9,0.4-2.9,0.6L414.7,38.6z M421.5,37.1c1-0.2,1.9-0.4,2.9-0.7l-0.2-1
    c-1,0.2-1.9,0.4-2.9,0.7L421.5,37.1z M428.3,35.6c1-0.2,1.9-0.5,2.9-0.7l-0.2-1c-1,0.2-1.9,0.5-2.9,0.7L428.3,35.6z M435,34
    c1-0.2,1.9-0.5,2.9-0.7l-0.2-1c-1,0.2-1.9,0.5-2.9,0.7L435,34z M441.8,32.3c1-0.3,1.9-0.5,2.9-0.8l-0.3-1c-1,0.3-1.9,0.5-2.9,0.8
    L441.8,32.3z M448.5,30.5c1-0.3,1.9-0.5,2.9-0.8l-0.3-1c-1,0.3-1.9,0.5-2.9,0.8L448.5,30.5z M455.2,28.6c1-0.3,1.9-0.5,2.9-0.8
    l-0.3-1c-1,0.3-1.9,0.5-2.9,0.8L455.2,28.6z M461.8,26.7c1-0.3,1.9-0.6,2.9-0.8l-0.3-1c-0.9,0.3-1.9,0.6-2.9,0.8L461.8,26.7z
     M468.5,24.7c1-0.3,1.9-0.6,2.9-0.9l-0.3-1c-0.9,0.3-1.9,0.6-2.9,0.9L468.5,24.7z M475.1,22.7c1-0.3,1.9-0.6,2.9-0.9l-0.3-1
    c-0.9,0.3-1.9,0.6-2.9,0.9L475.1,22.7z M481.8,20.6c1-0.3,1.9-0.6,2.9-0.9l-0.3-1c-0.9,0.3-1.9,0.6-2.8,0.9L481.8,20.6z M488.4,18.4
    c1-0.3,1.9-0.6,2.8-0.9l-0.3-0.9c-0.9,0.3-1.9,0.6-2.8,0.9L488.4,18.4z M495,16.2c0.9-0.3,1.9-0.6,2.8-1l-0.3-0.9
    c-0.9,0.3-1.9,0.6-2.8,1L495,16.2z M501.6,14c0.9-0.3,1.9-0.6,2.8-1l-0.3-0.9c-0.9,0.3-1.8,0.6-2.8,1L501.6,14z M508.1,11.7
    c1-0.3,1.9-0.7,2.8-1l-0.3-0.9c-0.9,0.3-1.9,0.7-2.8,1L508.1,11.7z M514.6,9.3c1-0.3,1.9-0.7,2.8-1l-0.3-0.9c-0.9,0.3-1.8,0.7-2.8,1
    L514.6,9.3z M521.2,6.9c1-0.4,1.9-0.7,2.8-1.1l-0.4-0.9c-0.9,0.3-1.8,0.7-2.8,1.1L521.2,6.9z M527.7,4.5c1-0.4,1.9-0.7,2.8-1.1
    l-0.4-0.9c-0.8,0.3-1.8,0.7-2.8,1.1L527.7,4.5z"/>
</svg>
```

The CSS:

```
.st0{
  fill: none;
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: 4;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  stroke-opacity: 0;
  transition: stroke-opacity .5s ease-in;
}
```

But it doesn't work. It should work like this:

https://codepen.io/nevolgograd/pen/WOLaKB

(But I don't need the buttons to activate the animation)

Any thoughts why it doesn't work?

Comment: The first problem is that you have your CSS class overwritten inside the `<svg>` element. You also will need to have a second state to "transition into". And if you want to animate it dash by dash, you'll need some JS code as it was in that codepen.

Comment: You just aren't animating anything. You have set a transition but nothing has been changed.

Comment: CSS properties must have units, your stroke-width really should have units.